# Get values and loop through an external json array

Tags: php, json

I want to make a countries database through PHP and Json. I have my data through an external json:

```
{
    "ph": {
        "name": "Philippines",
        "color": "green"
    },

    "ch": {
        "name": "China",
        "color": "red"
    },

    "us": {
        "name": "USA",
        "color": "blue"
    }

}
```

And I access them through php:

```php
$jsonfile = file_get_contents("mapdata.json");
$data = json_decode($jsonfile, true);
```

If I want, I could access individual data from each country for example:

```php
echo $data['ph']['name'];
```

However that would only work if I know `ph` in `$data['ph']`. If I will have 100+ countries and I want to make a for loop displaying their name and color, how could I achieve it?

It's kinda something like:

```php
foreach($data as $value){
    echo $value['something?']....
}
```

Thanks a ton!

Comment: you're close, inside the loop. just use `$value['name']`. or you don't know also for sure if it has an index `name`? then add another loop again

Comment: @Kevin thanks a lot! It worked. One more thing, how would I do it if I only want to display the `name` if the title of the array is `ph`? Like it would skip `ch` and `us`?

Comment: _if the title of the array is ph?_ there's the operative word already `if`, use an `if` statement inside the loop. _if the value is this -> echo this_

Comment: I tried `if($value == "ph")` then `echo $value['name']` but it displayed nothing

Comment: `$value` denotes the whole array in the current iteration, `$value['name']` denotes and pointing to the actual value. so you need to point it in the `if` statement too.

Comment: _“One more thing, how would I do it if I only want to display the name if the title of the array is ph? Like it would skip ch and us?”_ - then you would not loop over the whole array to begin with, but deliberately check if that key exists (array_key_exists, isset) - and then access the element directly, if it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kevin pointed out in the comments, to display the `name` value from the array, you can just use `$value['name']`. To only display values for the `ph` country, you need to modify your `foreach` loop slightly to get the `key` for each entry as well as the `value`:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 'ph') {
         echo $value['name'] . ': ' . $value['color'];
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Phillipines: green
```

As @misorude points out, if you only want to access the values of one particular country, it is more efficient to use [`array_key_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to see if values for that country exist in the array, and then access them directly:

```
if (array_key_exists('ph', $data)) {
    echo $data['ph']['name'] . ': ' . $data['ph']['color']. PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
Phillipines: green
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Qj5AQ)